# $W^2_p$ regularity of solutions of linear elasticity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $\Omega$ be bounded, polygonal, and convex, then for the solution of the linear elasticity (elliptic) equation with inhomogenous Dirichlet boundary data $g\in W^{2-\frac{1}{p}}_p(\partial \Omega)$:
>   \begin{align}
>  Lu &= 0, \text{ in } \Omega
> \\[3pt]
>   u &= g, \text{ on } \partial \Omega 
> \end{align}
>   it holds that 
>   \begin{equation}\|u\|_{W^{2}_p(\Omega)} \leq c \|g\|_{W^{2-\frac{1}{p}}_p(\partial\Omega)}.\end{equation}

I have found a result by Grisvard stating that a (unique) solution exists in $W^2_p$, but there is no stability estimate provided.

On the other hand there are results for the homogenous Dirichlet case (e.g. also by Grisvard) with a righthand side in $L^2(\Omega)$. So all I am missing is a continuous extension operator from $W^{2-\frac{1}{p}}_p(\partial \Omega)$ to $W^2_p(\Omega)$. Unfortunately I have so far only found the reverse, i.e. the existance of a continuous trace operator.

Can somebody point out a reference where either the original statement is shown or the continuity of such an extension operator is shown?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know that there is a linear bounded extension operator $E: W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega)\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: There is a theorem by Grisvard stating that for $C^{0,1}$ domains there exists a continous trace operator $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to W^{1-\frac{1}{p}}(\partial\Omega)$ which has a right continous inverse which does not depend on p.

Comment: If I had a $C^{1,1}$ domain the same theorem would give me the required extension operator. Unfortunately I am stuck with a rectangle /:

Comment: For $p = 2$ case, you can refer to Lemma 2.2 of [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2153060).